# Extending list class to make a list of objects

Tags: python

I have a particle list of objects of type Particle, which takes two parameters, position and energy:

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, energy):
        self.x = pos
        self.E = energy
```

The only way I've managed to do it so far is to create a list of particles using a list comprehension:

```
number_of_particles = 10
initial_energy = 0
particle_list = [Particle(initial_energy,i) for i in range(number_of_particles)]
```

which now allows me to do things like:

```
particle_list[0].x
```

which is what I want.

However, what I would really, really like is to do something as follows:

```
particle_list = ParticleList(no_of_particles, initial_energy)
```

and it create the exact same list.

I assume I have to extend the list class somehow but I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

Comment: You may define a method to do the same ?

Comment: Subclassing list might be possible, but it's probably the most difficult way of doing this. I think you're better off using a simple function that returns a list.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just build a function to do this for you. You could do something simple like:

```
def ParticleList(no_of_particles, initial_energy):
    return [Particle(initial_energy,i) for i in range(number_of_particles)]
```

This should be a simple way of getting your list.

Comment: @user1654183 I'd seriously consider doing it this way. The "factory function" way of doing this kind of thing is simple, effective, and is used a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, energy):
        self.x = pos
        self.E = energy

    @classmethod
    def make_particle_list(self, no_particles, initial_energy=0):
        return [Particle(i, initial_energy) for i in range(no_particles)]

    # this is just for display purposes
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'pos: {p.x} - Energy: {p.E}'.format(p=self)
```

This offers you a little flexibility. If you only need one particle you can make just one the normal way or:

```
>>> lst = Particle.make_particle_list(10)
>>> lst
[pos: 0 - Energy: 0, pos: 1 - Energy: 0, pos: 2 - Energy: 0, pos: 3 - Energy: 0, pos: 4 - Energy: 0, pos: 5 - Energy: 0, pos: 6 - Energy: 0, pos: 7 - Energy: 0, pos: 8 - Energy: 0, pos: 9 - Energy: 0]
```

This also allows you to pass in a different `initial_energy` if you ever need a different value.

You also had your arguments backwards in your example. You had `initial_energy` as the first positional argument in your list comprehension but you have it as the second in your `__init__()` method.

Comment: I like your solution! If you now replace both `self` and `Particle` with `cls` in your classmethod and do some starmagic, it will even work for subclasses of Particle ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create your class with your custom `__init__` method.

```
class ParticleList(list):
    def __init__(self, num, energy):
        self.particle_list = [Particle(energy,i) for i in range(num)]

particles = ParticleList(2, 0).particle_list
for particle in particles:
     print (particle.x, particle.E)

>>(0, 0)
>>(0, 1)
```

You may create your own method and not use the `__init__`, this way you will be able to simply return the created list and not assign it to a member (`__init__` is not allowed to have a `return` value).

```
class ParticleList(list):
    def create_list(self, num, energy):
        return [Particle(energy,i) for i in range(num)]

my_list = ParticleList().create_list(2, 0)
```

And as others have said, you don't even need the `class` and can get away with only creating a function:

```
def create_list(num, energy):
    return [Particle(energy,i) for i in range(num)]

my_list = create_list(2, 0)
```

Comment: You're not taking advantage of subclassing `list`. With your implementation `ParticleList` could also inherit from `object`. You should put `super(ParticleList, self).__init__( Particle(energy, i) for i in range(num))` in the constructor instead.